# Spark cassandra connector NoHostAvailableException will making multiple reads

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

While performing a multiple select in a mapPartition.
I do 2 prepared requests by row.

for advice the code look like this

```
 source.mapPartitions { partition =>
   lazy val prepared: PreparedStatement = ...
   cc.withSessionDo { session =>
       partition.map{ row =>
          session.execute(prepared.bind(row.get("id"))
       }
   }
 }
```

When the batch reaches ~ 400 row it throws a

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /localhost:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: [/localhost:9042] Pool is CLOSING))
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.reportNoMoreHosts(RequestHandler.java:216)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$900(RequestHandler.java:45)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:276)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.startNewExecution(RequestHandler.java:118)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:94)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:552)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeQuery(SessionManager.java:589)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:97)
... 25 more
```

It have tried to change configs to see if it can do something but the error is still poping

```
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "auto")
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "500")
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "100000")
  .set("spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms", "120000")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms" , "120000")
```

This kind of code work in [spark cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraJoinRDD.scala) but there is maybe something I haven't seen

After the exception was raised the next stream batches have no problems to connect to cassandra.

Did I timeout my cassandra with to much simultaneous requests ?

I use cassandra 2.1.3 with spark connector 1.4.0-M3 and driver 2.1.7.1

Comment: Did you try decreasing input split size and page size?

Comment: No, can you suggest values?

Comment: Depends, so just drop by 20% run and check for improvements, repeat.

Comment: 20% from what ? There is not dock for this param (spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb) I see 100K some where in the documentation. hsould i try 80K ? I also try to .set("spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec","1") ( a very slow value ) it's help but I have the same problem

Comment: Yes try 80k. What version of the connector? MB per sec isn't there in all versions

Comment: with 80K I have some time 3000 row ( 6K request ) witch pass successfully and some time 1500 row witch fail. I Don't understand why. what is the param for page size? I have edited my original post with versions